# Problemas con acentos y Ñ POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

En la base de datos se están almacenando una serie de registros. estos provienen de manera correcta con su UTF-8 , el problema es cuando se insertaron que algunos textos quedaron con unos caracteres �
en sus diferentes acentos o en las Ñ, el texto se ve así.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisando en el servidor el tipo de encoding y esto es lo que tengo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado cambiarle desde le servidor con lo siguiente

```
update pg_database set encoding=6 where datname='dbname';
```

donde en el encodig=6 remplazo el numero al que pertenezca la codificación pero no he obtenido resultados, ¿alguna manera de que pueda hacerlo?